# Does x86_64 have an equivalent to the aarch64 at instruction?

Tags: x86-64, arm64, page-tables

ARM's aarch64 has an AT (Address Translate) instruction that runs a virtual address through a stage of address translation returning a physical address in PAR_EL1, along with status to indicate whether the translation exists. See ARMv8 ARM, Section C5.5.

The question is: does x86_64 have the equivalent? Intel's System Programming Guide (Volume 3, Chapter 5) talks about pointer validation, but these methods seem to apply to segment-level protection, and there do not appear to be any page-level protection pointer validation instructions.

Is anybody aware of an ARMv8-AT-like instruction for x86_64?

Comment: I don't fully understand what the `at` instruction achieves. Does it return the physical address of a page table or something like that?

Comment: See ARMv8 ARM, D7.2.70. The `AT` instruction returns information in `PAR_EL1` (accessible at EL1, EL2, or EL3). `PAR_EL1` has the  status of the translation (whether the translation exists or not), along with sharability attributes, cacheability attributes, security state, and the physical address.

Answer (score 6):

No, the x86-64 instruction set does not have an instruction to perform physical-to-virtual address translation. It only has basic instructions like setting the page directory register, invalidating addresses, and enabling paging.

If you want this functionality on x86-64, I'm afraid you need to be in supervisor mode to do so. You would read the CR3 register, possibly change a few page table mappings to access the physical addresses you need, and perform the address translation by manually walking the page directory and tables.

Your question raises a question in response: For what purpose do you need to know about virtual-to-physical address translations? Paging is supposed to be transparent to application programs, and it is rare to have a good reason to know the physical memory address corresponding to a particular virtual memory address.

Comment: `at` is only available in privileged modes, so your last paragraph isn't too relevant. It's particularly useful for virtualisation, since when the hypervisor traps a fault from the guest (e.g. when emulating MMIO), it can simply run the faulting VA through a stage 1 (guest) translation to get the intermediate (virtualised) PA without having to go and find the guest page tables and map them in to grovel them manually.

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks for the additional info!

Comment: My research leads me to the same conclusion that @Nayuki confirms. Notlikethat's response illustrates a perfect reason for using this instruction: To eliminate the effort of a software table walk to determine what hardware obviously already has a mechanism to determine.